# When is it OK to create object of a class inside a method of that class?

Tags: java, class

```
public class TestClass(){
    public static void main(String []args) {
        TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
        t1.anything();
    }
}
```

Is it not strange to create a object in the definition of same class? Because then in response - this object creates a new object, then this new object creates another, and the infinite loop begins to never end until the memory is full.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is it not strange to create an object in the definition of the same class
>   than in response the object create a new object then this new object
>   create another and the infinite loop begins

No, the main method only runs once when you run your program. It will not be executed again. So, the object will be created only once.

Think of your main method to be outside your class. Which creates an instance of your class, and uses the instance created. So, when you create an instance from `main` method, the constructor is invoked to initialize the state of your instance, and then when the constructor returns, the next statement of your main method is executed.

Actually, you can consider `main` method not to be a part of the state of the instance of your class.

However, had you created the instance of your class inside your constructor (say 0-arg), and the reference as instance reference variable, then that will turn into an infinite recursion.

```
public class A {
    private A obj;
    public A() {
        obj = new A();  // This will become recursive creation of object.
                        // Thus resulting in StackOverflow 
    }
}
```

Comment: is it means that all the methods are out of the class definition only the class variable are created when a object is created ?

Comment: @RaviKumarMistry. I didn't say that. Only main method can be considered as outside class virtually. A class also contains other methods apart from main. They are in your class only, and a part of your instance state.

Comment: @RaviKumarMistry. The only reason we have to put main inside a class, is we cannot have methods outside any class in Java.

Comment: If only main is allowed to considered out side the class(virtually) than why not there is a provision to put main out side the class like c++ why we are restricted to put main in any one of the class.

Comment: @RaviKumarMistry. That is a part of language. May be just to be consistent with the philosophy of encapsulating methods inside a class, Java restricted the main method also to be in a class.

Comment: But what about if I do this?

class Test
{
    Test test;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         Test t2 = new Test();
    }
}
Would this be an issue or go into an infinite loop?

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks for the explanation, now is clear. It took me some time to figure it out, because it doesn't make much sense.  I would definetely prefer to see the main method outside the main class.

Answer (score 6):

You would only have an infinite loop (stack overflow error) if you tried to do the below:

```
public class TestClass {
    public TestClass() {
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
    }
}
```

And elsewhere, you try to create an object of the class `TestClass`.

Comment: I don't think so. if it creates infinite instances it must never stop but in my case it does, so something must be there to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class TestClass{
  public static void main(String []args) {
    TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
    t1.anything();
  }
}
```

This is a perfectly valid code. When the `main` method is called, no prior instance of the `TestClass` exists (it needs not, because the `main` method is `static`).

```
public class Test2{
  public Test2 clone(){
    return new Test2();
  }
}
```

This is perfectly valid as well. When you create a new instance of Test2, it contains the `clone` method, but the method is not automatically executed. Only when the `clone` method is called, one more instance of Test2 is created.

```
public class MyLinkedList{
  MyLinkedList next;
  MyLinkedList(int elems){
    if(elems>0){
      next = new MyLinkedList(elems-1);
    }else{
      next = null;
    }
  }
}
```

is perfectly valid as well, even if the constructor creates a new instance using the same constructor, because the creation is guarded by a conditional, so creating an instance *sometimes* triggers a new creation.

```
public class Fail{
  public Fail(){
    new Fail();
  }
}
```

Is the only problematic example here. The compiler doesn't complain. It *can* be translated into byte code and it *can* be executed. At the runtime, however, you cause a stack overflow:

- a new Fail is allocated
- its no-arg constructor is called
- the constructor tries to create a new Fail
- a new Fail is allocated
- its no-arg constructor is called
- ...

The compiler allows this, because, in general, the compiler *cannot prevent all infinite recursion*. The compiler *allows anything that can be translated into bytecode*.

The compiler, however, *may* issue a *warning* if it detects a method or a method chain *calls itself unconditionally*.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really odd.  All object oriented languages that I am aware of allow this.  The code is semantically part of the object definition, but in practice it can be considered separate from the actual state of any given object. So there is no loop because object construction doesn't call your method (unless, of course, it does - then you have a problem).

Answer (score 2):

It's not strange at all. You see, the `main()` method is the starting point of execution. So figuratively, java is "blind" (doesn't see what you've told it to execute/run) unless it has "seen" the `main()` method. It's after "seeing" the `main()` method that it now has the ability to execute other instructions that follow, so as a takeaway, the `main()` method literally doesn't belong to the object inside it's own class in the first place.

And for the recursion, it will only occur when you do something like what @Rohit Jain stated. Or per your code, you don't invoke `anything` but you rather invoke the `main()` itself.

```
    public static void main(String []args) {
        TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
        main(String[] args);
    }
}
```

The reference variable `t1` literally didn't invoke `main` because it's static. And the nice thing is that, `main` isn't invoked by your code rather the "jvm", so sensu stricto, you can't remove the static from there. It'll cause some good error message explicitly telling you that the static is supposed to be there. That's why you see `main()` not invoked by the object in the above snippet.

If you do one these then recursion will occur other than that, you are safe to create an object inside it's own class. Albeit, I wouldn't recommend that. Let one class have the `main()` method and instantiate (create object) other classes inside that Main class (the class that contain the main method). That way you get to run the code once.

Comment: Just an answer for those coming from the future. :D

Answer (score 1):

When you use new to create object constructors are called which initializes the instance variable this happens till all the constructors of your super class have been called  .
if you put the some code inside constructor that will run each time you create an object

Answer (score 1):

When a program starts it executes the main method. In java you cannot create a method outside of a class. All methods must be encapsulated within a class. Therefore the main method as an entry point to the program must be within a class. When you run this program the main method will be run once and will execute the code inside it. In your case it creates an object of the enclosing class `TestClass`. This does not have to happen. It can create objects outside of this class as well. You will only get an infinite loop as explained in the @adarshr's answer.