# Can I declare an object inside its own class?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm learning data structures. I have tried to do an exercise to order two stacks with random numbers keeping always them in order from min to max passing comparing and passing the value to another stack called `aux`. I have a method that fills them in order but I have a problem creating the object `aux` inside new class. I get the problem `<init>`. I don't what that means.

PD: After the stacks are in order I pass them to a queue that always has to be in order from max to min.

```
class Pilas {

    private int max;
    private int[] pila;
    private int tope;

    //Stack constructor
    Pilas(int n) {
        max = n;
        tope = -1;
        pila = new int[max];
    }

    //Method to push a value to stack
    void push(int valor) {
        pila[++tope] = valor;
    }

    //Method to pop a value from stack
    int pop() {
        return pila[tope--];
    }

    //Method to check if the stack is full
    boolean pilaLlena() {
        return tope == max - 1;
    }

    //Method to fill if the stack is empty
    boolean pilaVacia() {
        return tope == -1;
    }

    int seek() {
        return pila[tope];
    }

    **/* The problem that I have
     * Pilas aux= new Pilas(20)
     */**

    //Method to fill stacks in order
    void agregarEnOrden(int valor) {
        if (this.pilaVacia()) this.push(valor);
        else {
            while (valor < this.seek()) {
                aux.push(valor);
            }
            this.push(valor);
            while (!aux.pilaVacia()) {
                this.push(aux.pop());
            }
        }
    }
}

//Queue class
class FilaEstaticas {

    private int ar[];
    private int max;
    private int fin;

    //Queue constructor 
    FilaEstaticas(int t) {
        max = t;
        fin = -1;
        ar = new int[max];
    }

    //Method to check if the queue is empty
    boolean FilaEstaticaVacia() {
        return fin == -1;
    }

    //Method to check if the queue is full
    boolean FilaEstaticaLlena() {
        return fin == max - 1;
    }

    //Method to add a value to queue
    void agregar(int valor) {
        ar[++fin] = valor;
    }

    //Method to remove a value from queue
    int quitar() {
        int dato = ar[0];
        fin--;
        flota();
        return dato;
    }

    //method to move the position after removing a
void flota() {
        for(int i = 0; i <= fin; i++)
            ar[i] = ar[i + 1];
    }
}

class LaboratorioEstaticas {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int max = 10;
        FilaEstaticas fila = new FilaEstaticas(2 * max);
        Pilas p1 = new Pilas(10);
        Pilas p2 = new Pilas(10);
        int numero;

        while (!p1.pilaLlena()) {
            numero = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.println("Numero agregado a la Pila " + numero);
            p1.agregarEnOrden(numero);
        }

        while (!p2.pilaLlena()) {
            numero = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.println("Numero agregado a la Pila " + numero);
            p2.agregarEnOrden(numero);
        }

        while (!p1.pilaVacia() && !p2.pilaVacia()) {
            if (p1.seek() > p2.seek()) fila.agregar(p1.pop());
            else fila.agregar(p2.pop());

            if (p1.pilaVacia()) {
                while (!p2.pilaVacia()) {
                    fila.agregar(p2.pop());
                }
            } else {
                while (!p1.pilaVacia()) {
                    fila.agregar(p1.pop());
                }
            }
        }

        while (!fila.FilaEstaticaVacia()) {
            System.out.println(fila.quitar());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer thread discusses the problem in detail.
[When is it ok to create object of a class inside a method of that class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044983/when-is-it-ok-to-create-object-of-a-class-inside-a-method-of-that-class)

Comment: So is there a way to implement the method agregarEnOrden? I need aux to store the values that I pop from stack but I don't how to declare it or where

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at standard library of Stacks and Vectors and re implement . [Java Data Structures](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_data_structures.htm) If you really want to do a static declaration then use a static array like :                        int[] myIntArray = new int[3]; .

Comment: I passed the object as a parameter but it keeps giving me Array out of bounds error.

Comment: @JosFernandoValenzuela Please explain what you are trying to implement in detail and i will help you out. Please use English readable variable names.